# numeric overflow

Tags: sql, teradata

Does anyone know why I got a numeric overflow error from the following code?

```
SELECT distinct colA, sum(colB) as Total
FROM DatabaseA 
group by colA
```

most of the numbers are in millions and there are millions of rows. I think that's why? And how would you fix it? I tried to round it, but still overflow.

Comment: What is the data type on colB?

Comment: You could try casting that colB to a `bigint`: `sum(CAST(colB AS BIGING)) as Total` and see if that bigint gives you enough space to spit out the sum. If it overflows that, then you may have to go with a float and live with funky rounding errors.

Comment: Edit your question and show some sample data and the type of the column.

Comment: If it's a Decimal try casting to (38,n), or NUMBER. Btw, there's no need for adding DISTINCT to this Group By.

Answer (score 0):

check your data type. numeric overflow error ocurre when your value is greater than data type limit